# The order of execution of a code

Tags: python, tdd

I'm new to programming. Could anyone help me to understand the order of execution of a script? I have the code:

```
import unittest

var = 'one'

class FirstTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(var, 'one')

# del var

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

First of all I need to test my variable "var = 'one'". And then I have to delete this variable (del var). Without deletion of **var** (del var) the test passes. But if I delete this var from the scope the test is broken even if I place the test before the execution of **del var**.
I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

Either organisation of my code is unacceptable or I do not understand the order of execution of a script and when the tests are involved. So, where I can find any information to solve my problem - to pass the test and then to delete my valuable var? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The name `var` is a global and looked up *each time* when the `test_one()` method is executed. The method is not executed until the `unittest.main()` line runs test discovery and execution.

Comment: I resolved the problem. Thanks to answers and to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539316/execution-of-commands-after-unittest-main. So I need to execute my test using this code `unittest.main(exit=False)`

Answer (score 1):

Code in functions (and by extension, methods) is not executed until you call them. Names in functions are only *then* dereferenced.

The name `var` is a global, and is looked up each and every time you reference it. If Python did not, you could never use a global as a variable, you wouldn't be able to change their value as your program executes.

It is the `unittest.main()` call *at the end of your script* that (eventually) calls the `test_one()` method, so `var` has to exist until *at least* that point.

To be explicit:

- *declaring* a function with `def` will only trigger the creation of a function object, and then assignment of that object to a new name (the name following the `def` keyword). You need to actually *call* the function to have the code inside of it run.
- A `class` statement is a lot like a function declaration, but the body of a class is executed immediately to form the attributes of the class. So `class FirstTest(...): ...` is executed and you then have a new class object named `FirstTest` in your global namespace. This includes executing the `def test_one():` declaration inside, so `test_one` is then an attribute of the `FirstTest` class. The code inside of `test_one` itself is still not executed.

This means that what happens in your script is:

- `import unittest` is executed; the name `unittest` is added to your globals
- `var = 'one'` is executed, the name `var` is added to your globals
- `class FirstTest` is executed, the name `FirstTest` is added to your globals

  - While executing the class body, the name `test_one` is added to the class namespace, so the class has a `test_one` attribute.
- Optionally: `del var` is executed, the name `var` is *removed* from the globals.
- The `if` test is run. If true, the expression `unittest.main()` is executed. `unittest` is an existing global, the attribute `main` is found, and the object referenced by `unittest.main` is called.
- `unittest.main()` executes code that finds all test cases in the current module, here `FirstTest`. For each attribute on `FirstTest` that starts with `test_`, a test run is executed that calls that attribute. Here `test_one` is found and executed.

  - `self.assertEqual(var, 'one')` is executed

    - `self` is a valid local name, referencing the test instance
    - The attribute `assertEqual` is found, resolving to an object
    - the name `var` is looked up. It's a global, so it better exist!

Comment: Thanks. So, your explanation helps to understand why it gets an error. But how can I do - to determine a variable (1), to evaluate/test it (2) and to delete it after testing (3)? After unittest.main() nothing executes (I tried printing('smth') and etc.

Comment: Why do you want to? Python *exits* after `unittest.main()` and everything is cleaned up for you.

Answer (score 0):

It will read the outermost scope (non indented lines) first in one pass, top to bottom meaning if you define var, define a class that uses var, and then delete var, by the time the class gets instantiated (presumably in your main block) var is no longer available.

I'm not sure why you need to delete var but if it must be done it would probably be best done after `unittest.main()` indented in that same block